# Prove $(-x)y=-(xy)$ using axioms of real numbers

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers, axioms

Working on proof writing, and I need to prove

$$(-x)y=-(xy)$$

using the [axioms](https://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/courses/m361/F03/overheads/real-axioms-print-pp4.pdf) of the real numbers. I know that this is equivalent to saying that the additive inverse of $xy$ is $(-x)y$ but I am unsure how to prove it.

Comment: One thing you can do to start a proof like this is look at what other structures have this property.  For example, this theorem holds for matrices, so you can infer that any axiom of real number which doesn't hold for matrices (such as multiplicative commutivity and the order properties) won't be helpful in proving the theorem.  It holds in modular arithmetic in a non-prime base, so the unique inverse of multiplication isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 4):

You could prove that $(-x)y$ and $-(xy)$ are both the additive inverse of $xy$. Then use its uniqueness ($5^{th}$ axiom).

$$xy + (-x)y = (x+(-x))y = 0y = 0$$

Notice that $0y = 0$, because :
$$0y = (0+0)y = 0y + 0y$$
and if you add the additive inverse of $0y$ to both of the sides you come up with :
$$(-0y) + 0y = (-0y) + 0y + 0y$$
i.e. $$0 = 0y$$

Comment: how can we prove that $xy+(-x)y=0$? if we don't have $0.y=0$ we need this axiom otherwise we have to prove it

Comment: @Elaqqad $0y = 0$ can be easily proven. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how

Comment: Ok @Elaqqad , check my answer now.

Comment: Can i ask why the associative law is not enough?

Comment: Ok now it's fine , because I think that the main part is $0y=y$

Comment: Which of the associative laws, @ManolisLyviakis ?

Comment: Operation Axioms the first one. For all $x,y,z$, $x(yz)=(xy)z$.

Comment: @brick -1 is the inverse of 1 and it belongs to R .So i can take products and use the associative law .What am i missing?

Comment: Yeah, @ManolisLyviakis, I see that you use it in your answer, but it's not enough. It will be OK if you knew that $(-1)x = -x$, which is true of course, but it's not part of the axioms. It can be proven using similar stategy like in my answer.

Comment: @brick yeah i understood that a bit late cheers.Thanks.

Comment: I think you overlook an ambiguity in your answer...Your first (-0y) means (-0)y and your second means -(0y) in order to accomplish the cancellation, you are in a way begging the question.

Comment: To establish $0 = 0y$, add $1y$ to both sides.  I could point out that although invertibility of addition isn't an axiom, it does follow from the existence of an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Associative property: $$(xy)z=x(yz)$$
Then:
$$(-x)y=-(xy)\Longrightarrow(-1x)y=-1(xy)$$

When: $z=-1$

Comment: That still leaves it to prove that $(-1)x = -x$, assuming $-$ is defined as the inverse of addition.

Comment: To establish that $(-1)x = -x$, add $1x$ to both sides of the equation (although a real proof would probably use the existence of an inverse rather than the invertibility of addition, since invertibility isn't an axiom).

Answer (score 0):

First start by proving : -x = (-1)x.
Proof: x+(-1)x = (1+(-1))x = 0x = 0. The proposition follows from uniqnes off negative off a number.
Now you can use this to prove your statement.
Proof: (−x)y = ((-1)x)y = (-1)(xy) = -xy

Answer (score 0):

$$ 0 = 0 $$
$$ 0y = 0 $$
$$ (x+(-x))y  = 0 $$
Distributive:
$$ xy + (-x)y = 0 $$
Add $ −(xy) $ to both sides:
$$ - (xy) + (xy + (-x)y) = -(xy) + 0 $$
Associative of +:
$$ (- (xy) + xy) + (-x)y = -(xy) $$
$$ (-x)y = -(xy) $$

The master key is the distribution.

The axiom of distribution implies precisely what we want to demonstrate.

Without distribution, nothing links the operation + with the operation *. You would only have two groups on the same set.